# Create a copy of a postgres database while other users are connected to it

Tags: postgresql

I know two methods of copying a postgres database, but both of them require you to have exclusive access to the database, something you do not have while trying to copy a database from production in order to use it for testing something, like a software upgrade/migration.

```
psql>create database mydb_test with template mydb owner dbuser;
ERROR:  source database "mydb" is being accessed by other users

>createdb -O dbuser -T mydb mydb_test
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  source database "mydb" is being accessed by other users
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That worked:

```
psql
create database mydb_test owner dbuser;
\q
pg_dump mydb|psql -d mydb_test
```

Comment: now i have "ERROR:  permission denied" for any table in `mydb_test` database